# Match a number which comes before a string or after a string Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string

```
random -45 some 5-5-4-4-3-3-2-2-1-1 66 random 45- words
```

I want to match all numbers which comes before `-` or after it.

In my case, I need all the numbers except the number 66 as that number does not have `-` before or after it.

My regex

```
\d+(-)
```

This regex picks all the numbers where `-` comes after a number

```
(-)\d
```

This regex picks all the numbers where `-` comes before a number

How can I combine these two in one regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regular expression will work

```py
import re

s = "random -45 some 5-5-4-4-3-3-2-2-1-1 66 random 45- words"

numbers = re.findall(r"\d+(?=-)|(?<=-)\d+", s)
# ['45', '5', '5', '4', '4', '3', '3', '2', '2', '1', '1', '45']
```

It has two alternatives delimited by the `|`. The first alternative matches digits that are followed by a `-`. This is done with a positive lookahead. The second alternative matches digits preceded by a `-` using a positive lookbehind.

---

A naïve approach may have been `\d+-|-\d+`, but this fails to match the `1` right before the `66`. This is because the previous match already "consumed" the `-` character. Using lookaheads/lookbehinds avoids this problem.